# Drupal 7 How to remove Default Search Panel and Replace with Created one

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have created a search textbox and image button on my header and place it on the position I desire.

[image: Created Search Textbox and Image Button.img]

As I submit my keywords, the position of my created search items change its position and a duplicate of search textbox and button (Which I believe comes from the drupal module) appear.

[image: Error of the Search Items.img]

Can anyone assist me how I can solve this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The standard Drupal search box usually is rendered as a block.

To get rid of it, try going to Admin/Structure/Blocks then find that block and drag & drop it into Disabled region.

If you're not sure if it's a standard Drupal block, alternatively hover on that block then click on the wheel icon to edit it (you'll see it if you've contextual links enabled) then follow the page which controls it in order to disable it.

Comment: I have disabled the block. The error is still there

Comment: The 2nd image still appear

Comment: @desthj Do you've a wheel icon over it, what options do you've? Edit X? What's X?